# Android: Ids of Markers of Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have an app with `TabHost` and `Google Maps`. When I click on the tab that contains the `Map`, I do `map.clear()`. But this only cleans 7 `markers`. When I create the markers again, the id does not start from **m0** but from **m8**.

How I can start the ids of the markers from 0?

thanks

Comment: Why would you ever need to control them?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control what ids will be generated by the API.

One thing you can do is to remove and recreate whole `MapFragment` or `MapView`, but that's an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

```
Actually there is a trick to solve this .
```

//while plotting

```
int myId=0;

MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
          .position("YOUR LATLNG VARIABLE")
          .snippet(""+myId)
          .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.orange_map01));

myId++;

//then in the marker click listener function.
gmap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

System.out.println("The id you assigned will be available based on the     click  "+arg0.getSnippet());

//Do what ever you want to do with the assigned id , id will be created newly everytime.
Yourlist.get(arg0.getsnippet);



}
}
```